# How to sum all entered numbers before entering the largest number using loops

Tags: c

Let's say the user enters :

```
1, 2, 4, 9, 5, 3, 2, 7
```

output must be

```
 7
```

In this code program outputs sum of all numbers lower than max number.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, max = 0, zbr = 0;
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    max = n;
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf ("%d", &n);
        if (n > max)
            max = n;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (n < max)
            zbr = zbr + n;
    }
    printf ("%d", zbr);
    return 0;
}
```

Also when I enter max number as my last number output is 0.
Any help ?

Comment: Please edit the question and fix the indention.

Comment: Use formula `n * (n + 1) / 2` for sum of all numbers up to a number. If you mean only numbers entered so far then, store them in an array first.

Comment: `scanf ("%d", &n);` is not consuming the `,`. Check return value of `scanf()`.  Only integer read is the first one.

Comment: first you should learn to use the debugger so that you can see how the variables change as the program runs. then you will see how this code works. Next, start with a simpler problem; just read in the numbers and print them out.

Comment: The user should enter `1 2 4` etc. without `,`.

Answer (score 0):

This program respects your first task of finding the second maximum number.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
 {
    int n, i, max = 0, precmax = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);


    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (n > max)           /* Use 2 varibles to store the current and preceding maximum*/
        {
            precmax=max
            max=n;
        }
    }
    
    printf ("%d", precmax);
    return 0;
}
```

if your task is to sum all the numbers excluding the maximum then you can do as following

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
 {
    int n, i, max = 0, precmax = 0,sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);


    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (n > max)
        {
            max=n;
        }
        sum+=n;                /*Sum all numbers */
    }
    
    sum-=max;                 /*Remove the maximum*/
    printf ("Sum:%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```